# How to insert OLE Object (another .xlsx file) in .xlsx

Tags: python, openpyxl, ole, ole-object

Is there any option to add (Ole) Object to .xlsx file like that:
[image]

or

[image]

but using openpyxl?

I was trying to add it like image but

```
raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/home/file.xlsx'
```

I know that I can add it using `win32com.client` but I'm working on Debian with no possibility to use it.

And I'm expecting something like:

[image]

or

[image]